# How to prevent re-opening a scanned image's URL again after pressing back to return to the app?

Tags: unity, c#, augmented-reality

Simply, after scanning the trigger image with the phone's camera, the URL opens
successfully. When I press on the back button to return to the phone's camera,
the app reopens the URL again as you see in the attached video.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e5zcYL37WWLbkhqGt-XrmU9tYZQk-rx9/view?usp=sharing

Basically, I am keeping calling Application.OpenURL(videoClips[Image.DatabaseIndex].url) every time it hits the Update method. I need some sort of check to only open that when I want. I Maybe reset my image to null or something. Anyone can help me with this code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GoogleARCore;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;
public class AugmentedImageVisualizer : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private List<VideoLocation> videosClips;
public AugmentedImage Image;
public VideoPlayer _videoPlayer;


[Serializable]
public struct VideoLocation
{
public VideoClip videoClip;
public string url;


public static implicit operator VideoClip(VideoLocation v)
{
    return v.videoClip;
}
}

void Start()
{          
_videoPlayer = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
_videoPlayer.loopPointReached += OnStop;        
}

private void OnStop(VideoPlayer source)
{
gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
void Update()
{

if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState != TrackingState.Tracking)
{
    return;
}
if (!_videoPlayer.isPlaying)
{
    Application.OpenURL(videosClips[Image.DatabaseIndex].url);            
    _videoPlayer.clip = videosClips[Image.DatabaseIndex];            
    _videoPlayer.Play();
    Image = null; 
}

transform.localScale = new Vector3(Image.ExtentX, Image.ExtentZ, 1);
}
}
```

The second script to control the visualizer and the whole thing:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GoogleARCore;
using UnityEngine;

public class AugmentedImageController : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private AugmentedImageVisualizer _augmentedImageVisualizer;

private readonly Dictionary<int, AugmentedImageVisualizer> _visualizers = new Dictionary<int, AugmentedImageVisualizer>();

private readonly List<AugmentedImage> _images = new List<AugmentedImage>();

private void Update()
{
    if (Session.Status != SessionStatus.Tracking)
    {
        return;

    }

    Session.GetTrackables(_images, TrackableQueryFilter.Updated);
    VisualizeTrackables();
}
private void VisualizeTrackables()
{
    foreach (var image in _images)
    {
        var visualizer = GetVisualizer(image);

        if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking && visualizer == null)
        {
            AddVisualizer(image);
        }
        else if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Stopped && visualizer != null)
        {
            RemoveVisualizer(image, visualizer);
        }
    }
}

private void RemoveVisualizer(AugmentedImage image, AugmentedImageVisualizer visualizer)
{
    _visualizers.Remove(image.DatabaseIndex);
    Destroy(visualizer.gameObject);
}

private void AddVisualizer(AugmentedImage image)
{
    var anchor = image.CreateAnchor(image.CenterPose);
    var visualizer = Instantiate(_augmentedImageVisualizer, anchor.transform);
    visualizer.Image = image;
    _visualizers.Add(image.DatabaseIndex, visualizer);        
}

private AugmentedImageVisualizer GetVisualizer(AugmentedImage image)
{
    _visualizers.TryGetValue(image.DatabaseIndex, out AugmentedImageVisualizer visualizer);
    return visualizer;

}
```

}

Comment: Did you try clearing your image after opening it?

Comment: Please, could you help me with how can I do that? do you mean reset my image to null?

Comment: Please note that google drive content tends to rot, you should consider using an external service like youtube to host your videos. Although I agree that in this case the issue is well described and even if the video link rots, the question will still be well defined.

Comment: you could try simply adding `Image = null` in the line after your `_videoPlayer.Play();` inside the condition.

Comment: Where does a value get assigned to `Image`? You might want to include some hysteresis there, where when a *new* value is assigned to `Image`, you trigger an "On New Image Scanned" event that opens the URL, but you don't fire that event continuously every frame that the same image remains visible. If you can show us how `Image` gets assigned, we should be able to help you add this one-time behaviour to it.

Comment: Vaillancourt, 
Thank you! You are right, but this is for more clarification only to show the process on the screen. Many thanks for your notice!

Comment: Zibelas, 

Many thanks for your help, I appreciate it. I added the Image = null before and it seems to be working well, but the scale of Quad on the phone's screen is changed and It does not fit the image size!

Comment: If this solved your problem, it should be posted as an Answer below, not as an edit to the question. Otherwise future readers will get confused as to what the original problem was. 

Comment: Your scale might be messed up since you adjust it in update (once per new image should be enough) and it takes the size as well from the now null image. You might want to rework that with a simple if around your transform that checks if image is not null. And put it between the other two conditions else it might be first null before reaching there

Comment: Hi DMGregory, 

Many thanks for your comment! Basically, I added another script (AugmentedImageController) to control the visualizer and the whole thing. I am trying to add the code of the controller script above. If you can have a look

Comment: Hi DMGregory, 
I am sorry, I can't see the green mark! Could I ask you how can I post the comment of Zibelas as the answer?